# Operator-sdk : Naming Convention in Spec and Status structs

Tags: kubernetes, operator-sdk

I am developing an operator and wondering is there a link or document where the naming best practices are described for Spec and Status fields? For example:

Where I can locate all the info related to comments for each field or parameter to set field optional or set the default value a shown following:

```
// MyAppStatus defines the observed state of MyAppSPec
type MyAppStatus struct {
        // INSERT ADDITIONAL STATUS FIELD - define observed state of cluster
        // Important: Run "make" to regenerate code after modifying this file
        AppCount              int32                       `json:"appCount,omitempty"`
        Apps                 map[string]string           `json:"apps,omitempty"`
}
```

How do I set the default value for AppCount? Also, is AppCount is correct in naming? Can I have naming indirection i.e can I set it to the following:

```
AppCount              int32                       `json:"count,omitempty"`
```

This will help me exposing different names in the YAML file but inside the code, I will refer to AppCount. Please let me know if there a document for the comments beast practices on each field and fields flag such as omit empty or optional?

From the perspective of the comments, I have seen many operators refer to kUbeBuilder as shown below:

```
// +kubebuilder:object:root=true
// +kubebuilder:subresource:status
```

Where I can find the details of the above and when to use them?

Comment: Status fields wouldn't have a default since they are all going to start blank. And do you need a count? You can always take the length of the map.

Comment: Thanks. The above one is just an example. I was looking for some document for best practices around the naming convention in operator which should have 1) Indirect Naming like AppCoun in my code and count in yaml file for user 2) comments details related to optional and default values 3) Json tag values such as omitempty

Answer (score 0):

You can find the docs on controller-gen's annotations at https://book.kubebuilder.io/reference/markers.html (read the subsections). `omitempty` means the field is optional. The JSON name and struct name should generally be the same (except for case) unless you have a very good reason not to.

Comment: Thanks. Is Kubebuilder documentation is valid for operator-sdk too? Since there are many terminologies, I am trying to understand when to refer to Kubebuilder and when to refer to operator-sdk. As of now, I am using operator-sdk. Please provide your input.

Comment: Yes, operator-sdk uses the same underlying tools for Go operators.